# How to assign an object's value instead of the object's name

Tags: r

I have the folowing loop in R:

```
for (i in 1:length(M_names)) {
  for (j in 1:length(temp)) {

    q <- paste("M", j, "[", i, ",]", sep="")
    assign(M_names[[i]], q) 

  }
}
```

I want to create objects with the names stored in `M_names` and assign them `length(temp)` values from e.g. `M1[1,]`

My problem now is the following: The loop creates the objects I need with the correct names, but `assign()` does not instead the values of e.g. `M1[1,]` but this character string. So how do I chage this character string to the values behind it?

Next thing I want to do is to not overwrite the values with each j loop, but append them together but I will manage to do so later.

Maybe there is a much easier way without using loops but I am kind of new to R and loops seem familiar to me.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Markus

Comment: You are committing two cardinal sins. You create separate but related objects in the global environment instead of putting them into a list (a beginner should never use the assign function) and you create code with text processing. If you explain why you are doing this, someone could show you a better approach.

Comment: I had such a suspicion. Let me try to explain. I have a big load of measured data of different experiments in big matrices. I want to separate e.g. the first row of every measurement and compare them with the other first rows. The same for the second, third row and so on. The names of the rows give me information of what was measured, but if this is a problem I cna just number them and compare them to the list of measurements later.

Comment: `lapply(seq_len(nrow(mat1)), function(i) cor(mat1[i,], mat2[i,]))`? (I'm using `cor` as a proxy for your *"compare them*" function.) This assumes all matrices `mat1`, `mat2`, etc have the same number of rows. From this, you know the row because of the index within the returned list, so you can then name your new list here with `names(ret) <- rownames(mat1)`

Comment: So, you have, e.g., three matrices and want to do pairwise comparisons between the matrices for each row? What does "compare"  mean exactly? Some kind of distance measure? So far, I don't see a reason to put the matrix rows into separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are searching for the `eval()` function instead of the `assign()` function. The `eval()` function, together with the `parse()` function, can execute text and return the output. Let's see a simple example:

```
x <- eval(parse(text = "1 + 1"))
print(x)
```

The value for `x` prints out as `2`. I tried to work with your code to create a reproducable example:

```
M_names <- list(
  "M_name_1" = seq(1, 10),
  "M_name_2" = seq(1, 20),
  "M_name_3" = seq(1, 30)
)

temp <- list(
  "temp_name_1" = seq(10, 20),
  "temp_name_2" = seq(20, 30)
)

M1 <- data.frame(
  x = paste('m1', seq(1,3), sep = "_")
)

M2 <- data.frame(
  x = paste('m2', seq(1,3), sep = "_")
)
for (i in 1:length(M_names)) {
  M_names[[i]] <- vector("list", length(temp))
  for (j in 1:length(temp)) {
    q <- paste("M", j, "[", i, ",]", sep="")
    q_result <- eval(parse(text=q))
    print(q)
    print(q_result)
    M_names[[i]][[j]]<- eval(q_result)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never use `eval(parse())`. There is always a better (and easier) approach.